# Drawing polygons

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw the following picture using TikZ:

[image]

I've done this

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \foreach \x in {0,60,...,300} {
        \draw[fill] (\x:1 cm) -- (\x + 60:1 cm);
        \draw[fill] (\x:1 cm) -- (\x + 180:1 cm);}
    \foreach \x in {30,90,...,270} {
        \draw[fill] (\x:0.866 cm) -- (\x + 180:0.866 cm);}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \foreach \x in {0,72,...,288} {
        \draw[fill] (\x:1 cm) -- (\x + 72:1 cm);
        \draw[fill] (\x:1 cm) -- (\x + 180:0.809 cm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I would like know how to put this pictures together and fill the space within polygons.

---

This was my solution:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{fondo}{rgb}{0.898,0.996,0.898}
\definecolor{diagonal}{rgb}{0.466,0,0}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{scope}
    \draw[fill=fondo,very thick] (0:1 cm) -- (72:1 cm) -- (144:1 cm) -- (216:1 cm) -- (288:1 cm) -- cycle;
    \foreach \x in {0,72,...,288} {
        \draw[diagonal,thin] (\x:1 cm) -- (\x + 180:0.809 cm);}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
    \draw[fill=fondo,very thick] (0:1 cm) -- (60:1 cm) -- (120:1 cm) -- (180:1 cm) -- (240:1 cm) -- (300:1 cm) -- cycle;
    \foreach \x in {0,60,...,300} {
        \draw[diagonal,thin] (\x:1 cm) -- (\x + 180:1 cm);}
    \foreach \x in {30,90,...,270} {
        \draw[diagonal,thin] (\x:0.866 cm) -- (\x + 180:0.866 cm);}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can put the two figures together by using `scope`. To fill polygons, you need to make sure you actually have a polygon (i.e., at least three line segments in one `\draw`). I've done that in the code below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{scope}
    \foreach \x in {0,60,...,300} {
        \draw[fill=blue!25] (0, 0) -- (\x:1 cm) -- (\x + 30:0.866 cm) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=blue!50] (0, 0) -- (\x + 30:0.866 cm) -- (\x + 60:1 cm) -- cycle;
    }
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
    \foreach \x in {0,72,...,288} {
        \draw[fill=blue!25] (0, 0) -- (\x:1 cm) -- (\x + 36:0.809 cm) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=blue!50] (0, 0) -- (\x + 36:0.809 cm) -- (\x + 72:1 cm) -- cycle;
    }
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(The `cycle` keyword just means "draw a line segment back to the initial point in the `\draw` statement.)

And, just for my own amusement, here is a generalization that works for any n-gon.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\polygon[2][]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360/#2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\startangle}{-90 + \angle/2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{cos(\angle/2)}
  \begin{scope}[#1]
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,#2} {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\startangle + \angle*\i}
      \draw[fill=blue!35] (0, 0) -- (\x:1 cm) -- (\x + \angle/2:\y cm) -- cycle;
      \draw[fill=blue!50] (0, 0) -- (\x + \angle/2:\y cm) -- (\x + \angle:1 cm) -- cycle;
    }
  \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \polygon{5}
  \polygon[xshift=2.2cm]{6}
  \polygon[xshift=4.4cm]{7}
  \polygon[xshift=6.6cm]{8}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very nice code! And if you change this   \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{cos(\angle/2)} in to   \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{cos(\angle)}. You will get some very beautiful stars !

Comment: I've tried to understand the code but couldn't find to solve my problem. (and I don't want to start a new question). Is their a way the make an n-polygon and to color x parts of it. So continuing on this drawing, an octagon should be divided in 8 parts, and I would like to color x parts of it. The parts can (but it is not necessary) be against each other.

Comment: @Arne: can you ask a new question referring to this one? I have a solution for you.

Comment: @Yori I did now. Thanks. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273107/filling-a-percentage-of-a-regular-polygon

Answer (score 7):

Similar results can be obtained with a `regular polygon` shape. In this case, a `pic` helps to draw the node and fill it with those stripes in one macro.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    bicolor polygon/.pic = {
        \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=#1,
        minimum size=4cm, draw, fill=blue!50,
        outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) (-node){};
        \foreach \i in {1,2,...,#1}
             \draw[fill=blue!25] (-node.corner \i)
                 --(-node.side \i)--(-node.center)--cycle;
    }}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i [count=\d from 0]  in {5,6,...,10}
    \draw (4cm*\d,0) pic (a) {bicolor polygon=\i};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]